# Variable not interpreted on play2 template

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have an issue with Play2 template engine. Some variables are not interpreted during the rendering process.

The variable {key.getKey} is not interpreted when it was surrended by double quote. How i can solve this problem ?

PLAY 2.2.3 TEMPLATE (index.scala.html)

```
    @flash
    @(if (flash.size > 0) {
        flash.entrySet.iterator.map { key =>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                    <div class="alert-box radius {key.getKey}" data-alert="">
                        {key.getKey.toUpperCase} &mdash; {key.getValue}
                        <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    })
```

HTML OUTPUT:

```
    {"success": "The item has been created"}
    <div class="row">
       <div class="large-12 columns">
             <div class="alert-box radius {key.getKey}" data-alert="">
                  SUCCESS &mdash; The item has been created
                  <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

PLAY 2.2.3 TEMPLATE (index.scala.html) with @ variable

```
    @flash
    @(if (flash.size > 0) {
        flash.entrySet.iterator.map { key =>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                    <div class="alert-box radius @{key.getKey}" data-alert="">
                        {key.getKey.toUpperCase} &mdash; {key.getValue}
                        <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    })
```

HTML OUTPUT:

```
    {"success": "The item has been created"}
    <div class="row">
       <div class="large-12 columns">
             <div class="alert-box radius @{key.getKey}" data-alert="">
                  SUCCESS &mdash; The item has been created
                  <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** As it was unclear whether this was Scala or Java earlier, I've revised my answer to work with Play Java.

It appears that the templates work slightly different in Java, and the parenthesis around the `if` statement were messing things up. You don't really need the `if` statement anyway, as mapping an empty iterator will do nothing. This works:

```
@flash.entrySet.iterator.map { key =>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="alert-box radius @{key.getKey}" data-alert="">
                @{key.getKey.toUpperCase} &mdash; @{key.getValue}
                <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And if you really want the `if`:

```
@if(flash.size > 0) {
     (above code)
}
```

Comment: I've try your solution, unfortunaly, the variable still not interpreted (see my edited post). Code in the block "{ key =>"  is interpreted as a XML document (I get XML error when html tags are misclosed)

Comment: What is the type of `flash`? And is there more to this source file? I tried this myself (using just your code in the view) and it worked, so more information is needed.

Comment: it is the default flash var provided by Play 2.2.3. In my controller i've just put this code -> flash("success", "The item has been created");

Comment: Is this Play Scala or Java?

Comment: I use Play 2.2.3 Java

Comment: I've edited my response to work for Java. It would be good to tag your questions with java, as there are subtle (and not so subtle) differences between Play versions.